# Regex to capture hyphenated words separated by new line character

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I have a pattern such as **word-\nword**, i.e. words are hyphenated and separated by new line character.

I would like the output as word-word. I get word-\nword with the below code.

```
    text_string = "word-\nword"
    result=re.findall("[A-Za-z]+-\n[A-Za-z]+", text_string)
    print(result)
```

I tried this, but did not work, I get no result.

```
   text_string = "word-\nword"
   result=re.findall("[A-Za-z]+-(?=\n)[A-Za-z]+", text_string)
   print(result)
```

How can I achieve this. 
Thank You !

Edit:

Would it be efficient to do a replace and run a simple regex

```
text_string = "aaa bbb ccc-\nddd eee fff"
replaced_text = text_string.replace('-\n', '-')
result = re.findall("\w+-\w+",replaced_text)
print(result)
```

or use the method suggested by CertainPerformance

```
text_string = "word-\nword"
result=re.sub("(?i)(\w+)-\n(\w+)", r'\1-\2', text_string)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `re.sub` instead of `re.findall`:

```
result = re.sub(r"(?<=-)\n+", "", test_str)
```

This matches any new lines after a `-` and replaces it with empty string.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iekKP1/2)

You can alternatively use

```
(?<=-)\n(?=\w)
```

which matches new lines only if there is a `-` before it *and* it is followed by word characters.

Answer (score 2):

If the string is composed of just that, then a pure regex solution is to use `re.sub`, capture the first word and the second word in a group, then echo those two groups back (without the dash and newline):

```
result=re.sub("(?i)([a-z]+)-\n([a-z]+)", r'\1\2', text_string)
```

Otherwise, if there is other stuff in the string, iterate over each match and join the groups:

```
text_string = "wordone-\nwordtwo wordthree-\nwordfour"
result=re.findall("(?i)([a-z]+)-\n([a-z]+)", text_string)
for match in result:
    print(''.join(match))
```

Comment: Works ! Thank You very much. Could you explain the code very briefly please. Dont get the (?i) part.

Comment: It uses the `i` flag (case insensitive) so you don't have to repeat `[A-Za-z]`, which gets repetitive. Each word is captured in a group (the parentheses `()`), and then `\1\2` echoes both groups back to you, without the rest of the match.

Comment: It's an entire document. So I guess I'll use                                      result=re.sub("(?i)(\w+)-\n(\w+)", r'\1-\2', text_string), otherwise it captures all the words before and after.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace any occurrences of `'-\n'` with `'-'` instead:

```
result = text_string.replace('-\n', '-')
```

Comment: would it be efficient to do a replace and run a simple regex                       
text_string = "aaa bbb ccc-\nddd eee fff"
replaced_text = text_string.replace('-\n', '-')
result = re.findall("\w+-\w+",replaced_text)
print(result)                                                                                                               or use the method suggested by "CertainPerformance"                                               
 result=re.sub("(?i)(\w+)-\n(\w+)", r'\1-\2', text_string)